# Нужно сверстать блок(картинка 1) который при нажатии разворачивался и показывал другой блок(картинка 2). Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html

```css
.table-of-contents {
  background: #f2f5f9;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.table-of-contents-header {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.table-of-contents__hide {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-of-contents__list {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 30px 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.table-of-contents ol .level {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

.table-of-contents ol li {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.table-of-contents li a {
  color: #111155;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-of-contents">
  <div class="table-of-contents-header">
    <span class="table-of-contents__hide">
                                                Содержание
                                            </span>
  </div>

  <ol class="table-of-contents__list">
    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Хронология развития системы</a>
    </li>

    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Разработка приложений в HarmonyOS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Супер-устройство HarmonyOS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Поддерживаемые устройства </a>
    </li>

    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Бесплатная OC OpenHarmony</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Придётся использовать не только html, css, но ещё и js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> при нажатии разворачивался и показывал другой блок

Покажу вот такой вариант, без скриптов. Только `css`...

```css
.table-of-contents input {
  display: none;
}
.table-of-contents:has(:checked) .table-of-contents__list {
  display: block;
}

.table-of-contents {
  background: #f2f5f9;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.table-of-contents-header {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.table-of-contents__hide {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-of-contents__list {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 30px 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.table-of-contents ol .level {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

.table-of-contents ol li {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.table-of-contents li a {
  color: #111155;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-of-contents">
  <div class="table-of-contents-header">
    <label class="table-of-contents__hide">
      Содержание
      <input type='checkbox' />
    </label>
  </div>

  <ol class="table-of-contents__list">
    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Хронология развития системы</a>
    </li>

    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Разработка приложений в HarmonyOS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Супер-устройство HarmonyOS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Поддерживаемые устройства </a>
    </li>

    <li class="level">
      <a href="#">Бесплатная OC OpenHarmony</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Пример хороший, но не учтено, что там несколько аккордеонов идут, и при открытии одного, второй должен закрыться думаю.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, про аккордеоны и "несколько" речи не шло. "блок(картинка 1) который при нажатии разворачивался и показывал другой блок(картинка 2)".

Comment: согласен, но на картинке у него именно два раздела, он хочет реализовать что-то типа раздела FAQ

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, тогда у тебя есть уникальный шанс показать свой вариант для решения проблемы именно как видишь ее ты.

Comment: Показал свой вариант)

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, молодец.

Comment: Вы тоже молодец, не злитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, ты как-то странно интерпретируешь мои буквы...

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, оба варианта отлично подходят , затрудняюсь в решении выбрать принятый ответ ...

Answer (score 0):

Я в одном проекте так реализовал это.
Правда реализовано на jQuery, к сожалению JS плохо знаю.
Но как вариант работает, даже ваш css не трогал.
Также к table-of-contents-header добавляется класс opened, к которому вы можете сделать стрелочку при закрытом и открытом аккордеоне.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.table-of-contents-header').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
      $('.table-of-contents__list', this).show();
    }
  });
});

$('.table-of-contents-header').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
    $('.table-of-contents__list', this).toggle(300);
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('opened');
        $(this).siblings().children('.table-of-contents__list').hide(300);
    }
});
```

```css
.table-of-contents {
  background: #f2f5f9;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.table-of-contents-header {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.table-of-contents__hide {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-of-contents__list {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 30px 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.table-of-contents ol .level {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

.table-of-contents ol li {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.table-of-contents li a {
  color: #111155;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-of-contents">
  <div class="table-of-contents-header opened">
    <span class="table-of-contents__hide">Содержание</span>
    <ol class="table-of-contents__list">
      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Хронология развития системы</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Разработка приложений в HarmonyOS</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Супер-устройство HarmonyOS</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Поддерживаемые устройства </a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Бесплатная OC OpenHarmony</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="table-of-contents-header">
    <span class="table-of-contents__hide">Содержание 2</span>
    <ol class="table-of-contents__list">
      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Хронология развития системы</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Разработка приложений в HarmonyOS</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Супер-устройство HarmonyOS</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Поддерживаемые устройства </a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Бесплатная OC OpenHarmony</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="table-of-contents-header">
    <span class="table-of-contents__hide">Содержание 3</span>
    <ol class="table-of-contents__list">
      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Хронология развития системы</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Разработка приложений в HarmonyOS</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Супер-устройство HarmonyOS</a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Поддерживаемые устройства </a>
      </li>

      <li class="level">
        <a href="#">Бесплатная OC OpenHarmony</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за вашу помощь )